# Manipulating GeoPlots Effectively

Tags: plotting, manipulate, code-review, geographics

I've built a small interface for project because it's been a bit disorienting for me and others to quickly change the range on the plots. Eventually we'll tie different features of the data to colors but,  beforehand, I was hoping to improve the performance of the interface which leads me to ask for a review of my code.

The way to input the data might be improved? And I'm wondering if there is a more natural way to check the range is valid before rendering the plot? Right now the data is being parsed numerically instead of using the built in `GeoWithinQ` which I've been happy with but assume it could be better perhaps?

```
geoFilter[org_, coords_List] := 
 Module[{var, filtered, bounds, l, t} ,
  (* Numberically filters points which fall inside bounds from parcel \
data *)
  (* Set up *)
  bounds = coordassoc[coords];
  l = Length@org;
  (* Main Filtering Sequence *)
  filtered = org[
    Select[
     #lat > bounds[["lat", "min"]] && 
       #lat < bounds[["lat", "max"]] &&
       #lng > 
        bounds[["lng", "min"]] &&
       #lng < 
        bounds[["lng", "max"]] &
     ]
    ];
  (* Final Check *)
  
  If[Length@filtered >= 1, filtered, 
   Throw["No Points in Selected Area"]]
  ]

checks[{{minlat_, maxlat_}, {minlng_, maxlng_}}] := 
 minlat < maxlat && minlng < maxlng

boundedAreaGraphic[ds_, coords_] := Module[{var, pts, g},
  (* Input bounded region list : 
  Apply bounds and returns dataset with required features *)
  (* 
  Checks bounds of coordinates *)
  var = geoFilter[ds, coords];
  pts = GeoPosition[{#lat, #lng}] & /@ var;
  (* Output Graphics *)
  g = GeoGraphics[
    {AbsolutePointSize[4], Point /@ pts},
    GeoProjection -> "Mercator",
    GeoGridLines -> Automatic,
    GeoRangePadding -> None,
    ImageSize -> Large,
    Frame -> True,
    ImagePadding -> 40,
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style["Number of Existing Buildings in Bounds: " <> 
       ToString@Length@pts, "CodeText"],
    GeoBackground -> "StreetMapNoLabels"
    ];
  Print["Debug | GeoRange Plot: " <> 
    ToString@First@Values@Options[g, GeoRange]];
  g
  ]

Manipulate[
 If[
  checks[{{minlat, maxlat}, {minlng, maxlng}}],
  Catch[boundedAreaGraphic[
    data, {{minlat, maxlat}, {minlng, maxlng}}]],
  Nothing
  ],
 {{minlat, 49.24, "Min Latitude"}, 49.18, 49.41, 0.00001},
 {{maxlat, 49.292, "Max Latitude"}, 49.18, 49.41, 0.00001},
 {{minlng, -123.15, "Min Longitude"}, -123.2, -123.0, 0.00001},
 {{maxlng, -123.05, "Max Longitude"}, -123.2, -123.0, 0.00001},
 ContinuousAction -> False
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

***Added sample data for performance testing -- see Update below.***

The `Manipulate` controls for latitude and longitude allow the minimum values to be greater than the maximums. Is this the problem you want to fix in a more natural way?

I suggest a better method is to use latitude and longitude controls for the *center* of a region, and separate controls for the *dimensions* of the region. The dimensions can be a distance such as kilometers or miles. This way, the minimum and maximum values will always be valid (so there's no need to do `checks[ ... ]`). Here's a simple example that computes the values of `minlat`, `maxlat`, `minlng`, and `maxlng`.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   {minlat, maxlat} = 
     GeoDestination[GeoPosition[{a, b}], 
       GeoDisplacement[{Quantity[c/2, "Kilometers"], {180, 0}}]][[1, All, 1]],
   {minlng, maxlng} = 
     GeoDestination[GeoPosition[{a, b}], 
       GeoDisplacement[{Quantity[d/2, "Kilometers"], {270, 90}}]][[1, All, 2]]
   }],
  {{a, 49.24, "Center Latitude"}, 49.18, 49.41, 0.00001}, 
  {{b, -123.15, "Center Longitude"}, -123.2, -123.0, 0.00001}, 
  {{c, 5, "Latitude Dimension"}, 1, 10, 0.1},
  {{d, 6, "Longitude Dimension"}, 1, 10, 0.1}
]
```

[image: Manipulate example]

---

**Update:**

We need some sample data to do performance timing. Make random points centered on the `Manipulate` coordinate ranges.

```
{minlat, maxlat, minlng, maxlng} = {49.24, 49.292, -123.15, -123.05};
c = {Mean[{minlat, maxlat}], Mean[{minlng, maxlng}]}; (*center*)
ϕ = GeoDestination[c, {Quantity[10, "Kilometers"], {180, 0}}][[1, All, 1]];
λ = GeoDestination[c, {Quantity[10, "Kilometers"], {270, 90}}][[1, All, 2]];
SeedRandom[123];
pts = GeoPosition[Transpose[{RandomReal[ϕ, 5000], RandomReal[λ, 5000]}]];
ds = Dataset[<|"lat"->First@#, "lng"->Last@#|> &/@ First[pts]];
```

Set values for testing:

```
org = ds;
bounds = <|
  "lat" -> <|"min" -> minlat, "max" -> maxlat|>,
  "lng" -> <|"min" -> minlng, "max" -> maxlng|>|>;
```

We can improve performance of the filter (to about 40% of the original method) by combining the bounds tests, and by using flat variables.

Case #1 - original method

```
filtered1 = org[
  Select[
    #lat > bounds[["lat", "min"]] && 
    #lat < bounds[["lat", "max"]] &&
    #lng > bounds[["lng", "min"]] &&
    #lng < bounds[["lng", "max"]] &
  ]
]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.0199887 *)
```

Case #2 - Combine the bounds tests (faster)

```
filtered2 = org[
  Select[
    bounds["lat", "min"] < #lat < bounds["lat", "max"] &&
    bounds["lng", "min"] < #lng < bounds[["lng", "max"]] &
  ]
]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.0129947 *)
```

Case #3 - Use flat variables for bounds (fastest)

```
filtered3 = org[
  Select[
     minlat < #lat < maxlat && minlng < #lng < maxlng &
  ]
]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.00745205 *)
```

The filtered values are the same.

```
filtered1 === filtered2 === filtered3
(* True *)
```

*With the sample dataset, we can test the replacement `geoFilter` (I'll try it when I get back to a desktop version of MMA).*

---

Here's a drop-in replacement for `geoFilter`. It uses `GeoWithinQ` with a polygon computed from the latitude and longitude values from `coords`. Test this new method on your dataset to see if it's better.

```
geoFilter[org_, coords_List] := Module[{geopts, poly, filtered},
  geopts = Normal[GeoPosition[{#lat, #lng}] &/@ org];
  poly = Polygon[GeoPosition[
    Flatten[
      Table[{a, b}, {a, First@coords}, {b, Last@coords}], 1][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]]]];
  filtered = org[Position[GeoWithinQ[poly, geopts], True], All];
  If[Length@filtered >= 1, filtered,
    Throw["No Points in Selected Area"]]
]
```

The polygon coordinates are ordered beginning at the southwest corner, to the southeast, the northeast, and the northwest corners. `GeoWithinQ` finds the points that are inside `poly`. The positions of the selected points are used to extract the matching `filtered` values from the `org` dataset.